# Geometric series weighted by a cosine function

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometric-series

[Edited, corrected notation!]

I'm dealing with following series
$$ f_d(\omega) := \frac{1-d}{1+d}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} d^j cos(2\pi j \omega)  = \frac{1-d}{1+d}\Big[1 + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} d^j cos(2\pi j \omega)\big], $$
where $0<d<1$ and $\omega>0$.
In particular, I would like to prove that, for every $d_1, d_2 \in (0,1)$, 
$$  f_{d_1}(\omega) \leq f_{d_2}(\omega) \text{ if } d_1 \geq d_2. $$
Moreover, do you think is possible to compute the value of the sum for a given $\omega$? One can observe that, for $\omega = n \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_d(\omega) = 1$ and that, for $\omega = n + \frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$, $f_d(\omega) = \Big(\frac{1-d}{1+d}\Big)^2$. Is there a general expression for any value of $\omega$?
Can I at least say that 
$ \lim_{d \to 0} f_d(\omega) = 1?$

Here is a [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r2f44fho0j1o40r/stackex.pdf?dl=0) to a plot of $f_d$ for many values of $d$.

Comment: Considering your last limit, I think that should be $\frac{1-\Lambda}{1+\Lambda}.$ Of course you can say that since the weights are bounded uniformly by a constant.

Comment: Certainly $\lim_{d\to 0} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} d^j cos(2\pi j \omega) = 0$ since the terms are bounded above by $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} d^j $.

Comment: Also, for $\omega=\text{positive integer},$ the sum is actually $$\frac{1-\Lambda}{1+\Lambda}\frac{1+d}{1-d}.$$

Comment: In general the value of the sum can be easily computed whenever $\omega$ is chosen such that $\cos(2πj\omega)$ takes a constant value regardless of what integer $j$ is. In particular we may consider cases when the cosine becomes $0$ or $\pm1.$

Comment: As for the original inequality, this is equivalent to showing that $$\sum_{j>0}d^j\cos(2πj\omega)\ge 0,$$ where $-1<d^j<0$ for all $j.$

Comment: Thanks @Allawonder for your comments. I used the wrong notation in my original post: I used $\Lambda$ when I really should have used $d$.

Comment: @rogerl Given the absolute convergence of my series, to compute the limit, can I just bring the limit sign under the sum?

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to write
(Re means real part)

$\cos(aj) = Re(e^{iaj})$
so the sum becomes

$\begin{array}\\
s(d, a)
&=\sum d^j\cos(ja)\\
&=Re(\sum d^je^{iaj})\\
&=Re(\sum (de^{ia})^j)\\
&=Re(\dfrac1{1-de^{ia}})\\
&=Re(\dfrac1{1-d(\cos(a)+i\sin(a))})\\
&=Re(\dfrac1{1-d\cos(a)-id\sin(a)})\\
&=Re(\dfrac1{1-d\cos(a)-id\sin(a)}\dfrac{1-d\cos(a)+id\sin(a)}{1-d\cos(a)+id\sin(a)})\\
&=Re(\dfrac{1-d\cos(a)+id\sin(a)}{(1-d\cos(a))^2+d^2\sin^2(a)})\\
&=Re(\dfrac{1-d\cos(a)+id\sin(a)}{1-2d\cos(a)+d^2\cos^2(a)+d^2\sin^2(a)})\\
&=Re(\dfrac{1-d\cos(a)+id\sin(a)}{1+d^2-2d\cos(a)})\\
&=\dfrac{1-d\cos(a)}{1+d^2-2d\cos(a)}\\
\end{array}
$

Answer (score 0):

Here's an outline how to get started to find the sum $\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega).$You will need to apply the summation by parts formula twice. We'll use the forward difference notation: $\Delta f(j)=f(j+1)-f(j)$. Then the summation by parts formula is $$\sum_{j=a}^b f(j)\Delta (g(j))=f(b+1)g(b+1)-f(a)g(a)-\sum_{j=a}^b\Delta (f(j))g(j+1) $$To simplify notation,let $c=2\pi \omega$. Put $f(j)=\cos(cj)$. Note that $$d^j=\Delta (\frac{d^j}{d-1})$$ Thus $$\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega)=\sum_{j=1}^n\cos(cj)\Delta (\frac {d^j}{d-1}) $$. Note that$$\Delta \cos(cj)=\cos(c(j+1))-\cos(cj)$$ $$=\cos(c(j+1/2)+c/2)-\cos(c(j+1/2)-c/2)$$ $$=-2\sin(c(j+1/2))\sin(c/2)$$Thus when you applythe summation by parts formula, you get an expression similar to the one you started with, but "cos" has been replaced by "sin" and j has been shifted to j+1/2. Now apply the summation by parts formula again. Now you will get an expression in which "sin" has been replaced by "cos" and j+1/2 has been shifted to j+1. Use $$\sum_{j=1}^nd^{j+1}\cos(2\pi (j+1) \omega)=\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega)-d\cos(2\pi \omega)+d^{n+1}\cos(2\pi \omega (n+1))$$ Thus, after some algebra, you will have an equation of the form $$\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega)=A+B\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega) $$ which you can solve for $\sum_{j=1}^nd^j\cos(2\pi j \omega).$ Do the same for $\sum_{j=n'}^1d^j\cos(2\pi j \omega).$ and take limits as $n \rightarrow \infty, n' \rightarrow - \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! It took several hours, but I finally did it. I'll share here the results, should anyone be interested. 
After following the suggested steps taking the limit for $n\to\infty$, one gets
\begin{align*} \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} d^{j} \cos(c) &= 
\Bigg[-\frac{d}{d -1} \cos(c) - \frac{2d^2}{(d -1)^2}\sin\Big(\frac{c}{2}\Big)\sin\Big(\frac{3}{2}c\Big) + \frac{4d^2}{(d -1)^2}\sin^2\Big(\frac{c}{2}\Big)\cos(c) \Bigg] \cdot \bigg[ 1 + \frac{4d}{(d -1)^2} \sin^2\Big( \frac{c}{2}\Big)\bigg]^{-1} \\&= \frac{d\cos(c)-d^2}{d^2-2d\cos(c)+1}\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

$$ f_d(\omega) := \frac{1-d}{1+d}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} d^j \cos(2\pi j \omega)  \ne \frac{1-d}{1+d}\Big[1 + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} d^j \cos(2\pi j \omega)\big], $$

$$ f_d(\omega) := \frac{1-d}{1+d}\sum_{j=-\infty}^{\infty} d^j \cos(2\pi j \omega)  $$

$$= \frac{1-d}{1+d}\Big[1 + \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(d^j + d^{-j} \right)\cos(2\pi j \omega)\big], $$

Since $0<d<1$, we can write $x=\ln d$, so that $d=e^x$:

$$ f_d(\omega)  = \frac{1-e^x}{1+e^x}\Big[1 + 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \cosh jx \cos(2\pi j \omega)\Big] =\frac{e^{-x/2}-e^{x/2}}{e^{-x/2}+e^{x/2}}\Big[1 + 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \cosh jx \cos(2\pi j \omega)\Big] $$

$$ f_d(\omega) = -\tan \left(\frac{x}{2}\right) \Big[1 + 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \cosh (jx )\cos(2\pi j \omega)\Big] $$

$$= -\tan \left(\ln d^{1/2}\right) \Big[1 + 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \cosh (j\ln d )\cos(2\pi j \omega)\Big]$$

Not a proof, but experimental evidence:  *Mathematica* says that for $\omega \in \mathbb{N}$, the series for $f_d(\omega)$ does not converge, otherwise $f_d(\omega)=0.$